# How do you parse/cast (not sure of the term) unknown data types in java

Tags: java

I'm sure this has been asked a million times, but here goes.

I was trying to take a string value in java and parse or cast, I'm not sure of the term, into it's appropriate data type. I tried many a search, but I couldn't find the answer to presumably my lack of knowing the correct term. All the searches I've turned up have involved using things like XML or autoboxing which isn't near anything like want I wanted.

For example
The user input may be an int, char, or double such as 12.0, however it's captured as string in the code. How do I put it into the correct bucket so to speak? I don't know why I can't find a simple answer.

Edit:
I understand the Integer.parseInt(), etc below, but I was wondering how I would check for the appropriate type during runtime, through using a switch or if-else statments

Comment: There are functions per data type - look at example http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/number_parseint.htm

Comment: In your example you'd be parsing the data (and be subject to parsing Exceptions). If you want to cast data, you're asking Java to transform the information into a similar datatype. For instance you can cast integers to doubles (and this behavior is built-into the language)

Comment: The right term is "convert". How to convert a string to an int/date/double/... will probably return hundreds of answers.

Comment: But what if I don't know the expected value type. How can I determine it dynamically is my question? There are so many options to parse into.

Comment: That URL isn't loading for me, but you can go straight to the source: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html for example.

Comment: Thanks JB. Didn't realize the term was that simple. I am performing a search now.

Comment: Usually you know what kind of data's coming in and try to parse/cast it to its proper type. More advanced handling might use reflection and somesuch, but you'd better start small.

Comment: I was looking into using reflection. Is there an easy way to compare two data types? I suppose that would be a simple solution.

Comment: please go thru a full beginner java tutorial. will answer this and other questions for you. better yet get hold of a book

Comment: It doesnt say how to perform this task in the book I own, else I wouldn't be asking. Thanks anyway

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html

Comment: tutorial must see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/decimalFormat.html

Comment: How long is the list of possible datatypes you might have to parse?  Are you just talking about numbers?  Or are you talking about lists, dates, urls, file paths, etc...

Answer (score 3):

If the user enters something on the keyboard, it is a sequence of characters, i.e. a String, so this is what you get. Now, it might be possible to interpret that String as a number, a URL, or any other type.

If you know what kind of input to expect, you can use a parsing function for that particular type, e.g. `Integer.parseInt(String)`.

There is no general way to answer the question "What type does this string stand for" though, because the possibilities are limitless. The string "1" might be intended to represent an integer, or it could simply be a string, or it could be a Date representing one millisecond after the unix epoch.

If you limit yourself to a few distinct possibilities you can of course write a function like `Object parse(String)` which would convert the string to one of a few possible types which have non-overlapping string representations - e.g. Integer, Float, Double, Bool, Date (with a particular format) or fall back to String if nothing matches. However, this is rarely useful, and the range of types you need to support would quite probably still depend on your application, so you still have to roll your own solution. It could look like this:

```
Object myParse(String str) {
    try {
        return Integer.valueOf(str);
    } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
        // Not an Integer, try the next one
    }

    try {
        return Double.valueOf(str);
    } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
        // Not a Double, try the next one
    }

    try {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        return sdf.parse(str);
    } catch(ParseException e) {
        // Not a Date in format yyyy-MM-dd
    }

    throw new IllegalArgumentException("No matching format found.");
}
```

Finally, your String input might be in a known contianer format which denotes the type of the values along with their string representation - e.g. for an XML format: `<Integer>1</Integer>`. This would allow you to get an unambiguously typed value from a string, but it does require that the string follows a particular container format.

Comment: You exactly nailed my problem, and I understand all the inherent problems that exist, like the overlapping representation. I was just more or less trying to reconcile how to perform this task using java so that I may roll my own. Although useless, I've run into a situation in which I think it would prove helpful. I am diligently awaiting your response!

Comment: If this is really really what you need to do, you could create a list of parsers for all your supported formats and try them all on the input string. The result would be a list of all supported interpretations of your input.

Comment: I tried doing an initial parse search and all I get is XML, HTML, CSV etc which isnt useful. Do you know how I would compare types such that I may create said method? ie, if(Integer.parseInt(string) == true) else if (next case) and so on

Comment: `Integer.parseInt()` throws a `NumberFormatException` if it fails, so you can catch that and go on from there. I'll amend my answer.

Comment: Is there a way I can just check if it fails or succeeds within an if statement like in the previous comment. This way I can avoid a try/catch block.

Comment: In C# there is TryParse, I don't think Java has a direct equivalent. What's the problem with try/catch?

Comment: The problem I forsee is I would try/catch then if an exception is thrown, in attempting to reparse, I would have to try/catch the statement again. Repeat this until I get the correct type. Doesn't seem the correct way to go

Comment: @user2297101 - That **IS** the way to go if you **MUST** do what you're asking about (Java does not have an equivalent to C#'s _TryParse_).  You would have several try/catches in a row. In each try block you would attempt a parse, then return on the next (or same) line.  If an exception is caught, move on to the next try block.  I really think you should share your reason for asking this question.  My guess is we could probably steer you towards a better approach.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. I think I get what you guys are saying and how to implement it following your example. I guess I was just searching for an easier method that, unlike C+, java doesnt provide. Cant wait to get this up an running

Answer (score 1):

> The user input may be an int, char, or double such as 12.0.

If the input is truly unknown, you're going to have problems converting the input.  For example, is "1" (without the quote marks) a char or an int?

Each input type has its own conversion.  For example:

```
String s = "test string";

char c = s.charAt(0);
int i = Integer.parseInt(s);
double d = Double.parseDouble(s);
```

You'll get a NumberFormatException if the string isn't an int or a double, respectively.

Comment: I understand the aforementioned problems, but how can I take string value and correctly Integer.parse, Double.parse, etc, though I'm not sure what other type conversions there are

Comment: go thru a tutorial will learn exception handling http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/